# How do I find out to what hostname a potential malware wants to connect?

Tags: hostname, sniffing, spyware, netstat, tcpdump

Without connecting my computer to Internet. 
I can only think about netstat and packet capturing tools, but I dont really know which method is suitable.

Comment: Well if you disconnect your machine from the network and close everything so nothing else is trying to communicate you can run Wireshark and monitor the NIC but you might still end up with a lot of packets to shift through and dig out anything related to Malware (that may or may not actually 1. be on your machine or 2. try to communicate if it knows the network is not external facing or disabled)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try Wireshark. But I'm still looking for an easier solution, like Little Snitch. Although its only available for OSX, I find it useful because I could check spyware installed on any device that try to connect to remote hosts. I only need to know how to route the traffic from those devices to my computer. But I dont want my computer to be connected to internet, although I dont mind if its connected to intranet, and I'm not sure about how to put together all these concepts: DNS, netstat, routing etc

Comment: Another good free network monitor is called network miner.   It's on sourceforge and much easier to use than wire shark.